# Get the Orginal url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am rewriting the URL, In that I want to get the original url.when user request the below url:
**http://test.acom/test12.htm** the original url of this request is below

**http://test.acom/cms.aspx?pid=123** when

now I want to find out the original url
how can I got that, please guide me.

Comment: How is the URL being rewritten?

Comment: Probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678371/url-rewriting-in-asp-net-but-maintaining-the-original-url

Comment: I have save the requested url in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request.RawUrl` to get the originally requested URL by the client. This URL is always relative, so in your case, it would read `/test12.htm`.

Comment: but I want url something look like:
/cms.aspx?pid=123

Comment: If you want the original url with the querystring, try request.url as in my asnswer above - includes an example too.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me `Request.Url`.

I use a custom rewriting url class that changes urls from `articles/displayarticle.aspx?ArticleID=73` to `articles/Build-a-file-tree-explorer-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx`

Note this a webforms site also.

With `request.url` I get `articles/displayarticle.aspx?ArticleID=73`